# Error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to get an Arduino to work with some Adafruit Motor shields. 
Everything seemed to work fine, but when I tried to create a function, I get the error in the subject. As far as I can tell, everything was declared properly (the array is initialized and is indexed elsewhere with without issue). Only the function seems to cause an issue.

Would anyone have a guess at what's wrong?

```
    //////// Imports
    #include <Wire.h>
    #include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
    #include "utility/Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h"

    ////////My globals. Times are in milliseconds
    unsigned long currentTime = 0;
    unsigned long elapsedTime = 0;
    unsigned long startTime = 0;
    byte currentMotor = 1;
    byte currentShield = 1;
    byte motorRunning = 0;

    //// Settings

    // How many seconds between motors
    unsigned long endTime = 4000;

    // How many shields and motors per shield
    const int nShields = 1;
    const int nMotorsPerShield = 3;

    /////////MicroManager globals
    unsigned int version_ = 2;
    const unsigned long timeOut_ = 1000;
    byte currentPattern_ = 0;
    unsigned long time;

    /////////Adafruit globals
    Adafruit_MotorShield afms[nShields];
    Adafruit_DCMotor *motor[nShields][nMotorsPerShield];

    ////////////Setup
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(57600);

      unsigned char address = 96;

      for (int i = 0; i < nShields; i++) {
        afms[i] = Adafruit_MotorShield(address);
        address = ++address;
        afms[i].begin();
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < nShields; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nMotorsPerShield; j++) {
          motor[i][j] = afms[i].getMotor(j + 1);
          motor[i][j]->setSpeed(255);
        }
      }

      pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    }

    ////////////////////Main
    void loop() {
      currentTime = millis();
      elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;

      if (elapsedTime > endTime) {
        startTime = currentTime;
        currentMotor = currentMotor + 1;
        if (currentMotor > nMotorsPerShield) {
          currentMotor = 1;
        }
      }

      if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        int inByte = Serial.read();

        switch (inByte) {
          case 1:
            if (waitForSerial(timeOut_)) {
              currentPattern_ = Serial.read();
              if (currentPattern_ == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < nShields; i++) {
                  for (int j = 0; j < nMotorsPerShield; j++) {
                    motor[1][j]->run(RELEASE);
                  }
                }
              }
              else {
                switchMotor();
              }
              Serial.write( byte(1));
              digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
            }
            break;

          case 30:
            Serial.println("MM-Ard");
            break;

          case 31:
            Serial.println(version_);
            break;
        }
      }

      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    }


    ////////////////Function definitions

    bool waitForSerial(unsigned long timeOut)
    {
      unsigned long starTime = millis();
      while (Serial.available() == 0 && (millis() - starTime < timeOut) ) {}
      if (Serial.available() > 0)
        return true;
      return false;
    }

    void switchMotor()
    {
      int shield = currentShield - 1;
      int motor = currentMotor - 1;
      for (int i = 0; i < nShields; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nMotorsPerShield; j++) {
          if (i == shield && j == motor)
            motor[i][j]->run(FORWARD);
          else
            motor[i][j]->run(RELEASE);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the full error message from the compiler. And the code where it occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a close look at this line:

```
motor[1][j]->run(RELEASE);
```

Looks like it should be:

```
motor[i][j]->run(RELEASE);
```

Otherwise it is an illegal index (as there is only one shield).

The next error is in the function switchMotor(). Again, have a close look at the definition of "motor". There is a local variable with that name but you want to also access the global array with the same name.

```
void switchMotor()
{
  int shield = currentShield - 1;
  int motor = currentMotor - 1;
      ^
  for (int i = 0; i < nShields; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nMotorsPerShield; j++) {
      if (i == shield && j == motor)
        motor[i][j]->run(FORWARD);
        ^
      else
        motor[i][j]->run(RELEASE);
    }
  }
}
```

My guess is that this is where the compiler give you the error message!

Cheers!

Comment: To be able to help you must add the compiler error output with line, file, and the code. It is too much guessing otherwise.

Comment: Changing the `int motor =` and the `j == motor` to `xmotor` instead of `motor` allows it to compile perfectly fine for me. Just get rid of that variable naming conflict and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Mikael, the motor naming conflict was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I get a warning flag in UECIDE for the line:

```
address = ++address;
```

> ‣ operation on 'address' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]

Increment address, and then assign the new value from address into address.  That seems a bit odd to me.  I think you just meant to increment:

```
address++;
```

Or

```
address = address + 1;
```

Also it flags up the `1` instead of `i` that Mikael found:

> ‣ array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]

And of course there is the (somewhat hard to spot - Kudos to Mikael for finding it - it took me a bit to see it myself) naming conflict:

> ‣ invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

It was only when I used the advanced editing facilities of UECIDE to highlight all occurrences of `motor` that I found there was extra ones that shouldn't have been there causing the problem.

[image]

So just changing the integer variable name from `motor` to something else fixes it:

```
void switchMotor()
{
  int shield = currentShield - 1;
  int thismotor = currentMotor - 1;       // RENAMED MOTOR
  for (int i = 0; i < nShields; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nMotorsPerShield; j++) {
      if (i == shield && j == thismotor)  // RENAMED MOTOR
        motor[i][j]->run(FORWARD);
      else
        motor[i][j]->run(RELEASE);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, that was the issue!